# how can i get the text box for a view? in my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textbox

I follow this example to make  n to n relations

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

it work fine but for the n to n relations with payload to the database i figure out and I  can do the  [HttpGet] and show the view what i want to show but now i want to know how can i get the textbox I have in my view, I can get the checkbox in my controller (see see below the action) and this is my view so my question will be how can get the textbox too? in my controller for every checkbox?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AgregarEmpresas", "Empleado"))
{

  <fieldset>
 <div class="editor-field">
    <table>
       <tr>
            @{
                int cnt = 0;
                List<ITCOrganigrama.ViewModel.AsignarEmpresa> empresas = ViewBag.Empresas;

                foreach (var empresa in empresas)
                {
                    if (cnt++ % 5 == 0) {
                        @:  </tr> <tr> 
                    }
                    @: <td> 
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                               name="selectedEmpresa" 
                               value="@empresa.EmpresaId" 
                               @(Html.Raw(empresa.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> 
                          @empresa.Nombre
                      <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => empresa.cargo)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => empresa.cargo, new { style = "width: 150px;" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => empresa.cargo)
                         </div>
                    @:</td>
                }
                @: </tr>
            }
    </table>
</div>
 <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Agregar" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

the action where i get the chekbox

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AgregarEmpresas(int? id, FormCollection formCollection, string[] selectedEmpresa)
        {
}
```

my final view:
http://s3.subirimagenes.com:81/otros/previo/thump_7406511add1.jpg
http://www.subirimagenes.com/otros-add1-7406511.html

Edited:

ViewModel Class

```
public class AsignarEmpresa
    {
        public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string cargo { get; set; }
        public bool Assigned { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your post action and it's parameters. Names of those are really important.

Your checkboxes

```
 <input type="checkbox" 
                           name="selectedEmpresa" 
                           value="@empresa.EmpresaId"
```

are working fine beacuse look at the name of the input its "**selectedEmpresa**" it's the same name as in **Controller Action** definition. Model binder looks for this name in posted data and if he finds it, he  creates object from it. In your case he will try to parse data into **string[]** object.

So ... first of all you have to change action definition to something like.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AgregarEmpresas(int? id, FormCollection formCollection, string[] selectedEmpresa,string [] empresaTextBox)
        {
}
```

Then you have to change generated html.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => empresa.cargo, new { style = "width: 150px;", name="empresaTextBox" })
```

With those changes you should get some data inside **Action**. However you will get something weird beacuse you have multiple **checkboxes** and **textboxes** in order to tell model binder that there are multiple elements of those you have to prepare special name of inputs that contains index number.

Look at this example

```
<input name="childs[0]"></input>
<input name="childs[1]"></input>
```

In this case **Model Binder** will create array of objects that contains 2 of them.

So finally your code would have to look like this.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AgregarEmpresas", "Empleado"))
{

  <fieldset>
 <div class="editor-field">
    <table>
       <tr>
            @{
                int cnt = 0;
                int i=0;
                List<ITCOrganigrama.ViewModel.AsignarEmpresa> empresas = ViewBag.Empresas;

                foreach (var empresa in empresas)
                {
                    if (cnt++ % 5 == 0) {
                        @:  </tr> <tr> 
                    }
                    @: <td> 
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                               name="selectedEmpresa[@i]" 
                               value="@empresa.EmpresaId" 
                               @(Html.Raw(empresa.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> 
                          @empresa.Nombre
                      <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => empresa.cargo)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => empresa.cargo, new { style = "width: 150px;" ,name=String.Format("empresaTextBox\[{0}\]",i) })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => empresa.cargo)
                         </div>
                    @:</td>
                i++;
                }
                @: </tr>

            }
    </table>
</div>
 <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Agregar" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

If you will get this to work. Then i would try to create a class with one **boolean** and one **string** value. With this change you would operate on the array of classes instead of two arrays with strings.

Comment: a do that bu in my action i get null for the empresaTextBox

i have in my viewmodel a class with boolean and string